# Panel not moving as intended

Tags: c#

I have a sliding panel that opens when I click a button but when I want it to close in doesn't do anything what am I doing wrong? I've tried using various timers but nothing seems to work.

```
    public void open()
    {
        if (panel2.Location.X < 125)
        {
            panel1.Width--;
            panel2.Width--;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        open();
        timer1.Interval = 10 * (1);
    }
    public void close()
    {
        if (panel2.Location.X > 125)
        {
            panel1.Width++;
            panel2.Width++;
        }
    }

    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        close();
        timer2.Interval = 10 * (1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, if the `panel2` has an `X` coordinate less than or equal to 125 the `close` method doesn't resize anything.

Probably there is something wrong in your logic (whatever you are attempting to do).
In the `open` method you decrease the `width` of the two panels only if the `panel2` has an X coordinate less than 125.

Of course, having panel2 an X coordinate less than 125 means that the close method can't increase the width.

Comment: Oh ok will have another look